# How do electoral college votes work with Indian reservations?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college, indigenous-people

As far as I know, citizens from Indian reservations can vote for president, but every-time we see discussions about Presidential elections, votes are assigned by the electoral college per state. How do their votes for President count? Are they assigned to a particular state?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Native Americans (like everyone else) register to vote in the state they are physically based in -- if they can provide an address, which can be difficult. Voter registration rules differ between states.

> Many Native Americans, especially those who live on reservations, do not have traditional street addresses. This has resulted in voter registration applications being rejected in many states.

([Source: Brennan Center for Justice](https://www.brennancenter.org/our-work/analysis-opinion/state-native-american-voting-rights))

> County by county, election administrators must know exactly where voters live to assign accurate precincts, which then determine which ballot a voter receives, which offices she votes for and at which polling location she casts a ballot. In Utah and many other largely rural states, residents can register to vote by describing their approximate location on registration forms, or even draw a rudimentary map, which is allowed by the National Voter Registration Act of 1993.

([Source: Pew](https://www.pewtrusts.org/en/research-and-analysis/blogs/stateline/2019/10/04/for-some-native-americans-no-home-address-might-mean-no-voting))